# Binding an array of json results to html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I'm pretty new to angularjs, and getting a json result set that I'd like to display. I have the following;

Service:

```
var Post = function(data) {
    angular.extend(this, data);
}

Post.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/posts').then(function(response) {
        var Posts = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            Posts.push(new Post(response.data[i]));
        }
        return Posts;
    });
};
```

Controller method:

```
$scope.Posts = Posts.getAll();
```

html view:

```
<ul ng-repeat="post in Posts">
    <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that while everything repeats correctly, I cannot access the members of each object. eg: post.title or post.text does not display. However, if I use {{ post }} it displays the json for the entire result.

Where am I going wrong here?

Edit: I've just seen thanks to the comment below that if I use

```
post[0].title
```

It correctly displays, however is this the correct way to be displaying an array of json results? I'd prefer to use the correct method, vs the one that "just works".

Comment: Could it be the way you are accessing it? What does {{post}} show?

Comment: {{ post }} shows the json for that whole row, eg "{"0":{"title":"Test title","introduction":"test introduction.." I'm unsure about how I can transform the object so that I can bind {{ post.title }} or if there's another way I should be binding it.

Comment: From the way your data is returned, that (`post[0].title`) is the right approach. You could change the data source to remove the `{"0":`

Comment: Yes, post[index].title is the correct way to bind to your JSON

Comment: What does {{post}} show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments by ranru and Zack Argyle, I simply needed to add the index to post, eg: post[0].title.